# Finding letters in a string while ignoring everything else

Tags: c++

For my homework, part of what I need to do is take a phrase from the user, and from there take only the letters in the phrase, ignoring numbers, spaces, and special characters.  Once I find letters in the string, I need to store them into a separate variable.  However, I can't get that variable to store anything outside of the `if` statement that looks for letters.

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string line, temp;
    cout << "Enter phrase to check:  ";
    getline(cin, line);
    
    for(int i = 0; i < line.size(); i++)
    {
        if((line[i] > 64 && line[i] < 91) || (line[i] > 96 && line[i] < 123))
        {
            temp[i] = line[i];
        }
    }

    cout << temp;
    return 0;
}
```

When I run the program, `temp` outputs nothing.  But I know the `if` statement is correctly finding letters, from making it print `line[i]` inside the `if` statement.

Comment: How should I increment the index? At the end of the if statement? or after the if statement in the for loop?

Comment: @PatrickTrinidad At the end of the if statement. But does string's bracket operator works for setting? You might want to do `temp += line[i]` or `temp.push_back(line[i])`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your `temp` variable is an empty string. `temp[x]` is telling the compiler to change the `x`-th character of that string(which doesn't make any sense, as the string doesn't have any characters!). You're lucky(or unlucky) that you aren't getting any Segmentation faults(crashes).

Just use the `+=` operator:

```
temp += line[i];
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that having an empty string did that.  Thank you very much, doing += worked. I appreciate you taking time to help me.

Comment: @PatrickTrinidad If an answer helped you and answered the question, you can mark it as `accepted` by clicking the checkmark on the left :).

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
temp.push_back(line[i]);
```

It will work.

Answer (score 0):

The way you're currently doing it (`temp[i] = line[i];`) means that each non special character in line will be placed at the same index in temp. This should usually fail since temp (a `string`) does not resize on indexing.

For changing the size of a string, there exists a function called `string::push_back` as detailed [here](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/push_back/).

Instead of indexing using `temp[i]`, you would instead use `temp.push_back(line[i]);`

This function allows the string to resize itself to accommodate the new char if need be and won't throw a [segmentation fault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346806/what-is-a-segmentation-fault/2346849#2346849).

NB: `std::string::push_back` is designed to append a single char to a string. There exist multiple other ways of doing this, including [Nikita Demodov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66414592/4896472) which shows the use of the `+=` operator which is much more lenient and will allow appending of other strings etc. `push_back` is most common to the std::vector where it is used to append single items to the list.